# A Game with Polynomials

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $P_1(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$ and  $P_2(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n  b_ix^i$ be two polynomials of the same degree $n$.
Each time a coin is thrown, if it turns up heads then we do the following:

**Step 1.** A number is uniformly and randomly chosen from the set $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}$. If it is $i$ and $a_i\neq 0$ then $a_i$ is set to $0$,

**Step 2.** else we keep on choosing  a number  randomly and uniformly from the same set till it returns a number number $j$  s.t. and $a_j \neq 0$  and  set $a_j$ to $0$.

On the other hand if the coin turns up tails we do the Steps 1 and 2 for the coefficients $b_k$, $k=0,1,2,\ldots n$. We stop when  all the coefficients of one  of polynomials become all zero for the first time.

If $D$ is the degree of the remaining  polynomial, how can  we find the expected value $\mathbf{E}(D)$ of $D$?

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: Are you sure in step 2 you want to repeat until $j=0$? Not until $a_j=0$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen sorry typo.i want to repeat till j get j st $a_j\neq 0$

Comment: Equivalently, let  $A$ and $B$ be tow finite sets of non-negative integers. Depending by the outcome of a fair coin, we remove a random element from $A$ or a random element from $B$, and repeat until one of the sets becomes empty. Let $D$ be the largest integer surviving. What is $\mathbf{E}(D)$?

Comment: Exactly .That is a far more simple way of formulating the problem.We may also then calculate the expected number of elements in the surviving set

Comment: The largest remaining and the number remaining are two different things.  We know that if the set starts with $n$ numbers and we end with $k$ the expected value of the largest is $\frac {kn}{k+1}$

Comment: @RossMillikan could you please give hint

Comment: I don't have an answer, I was just pointing out the difference and linkage in the questions.